# Prestosql/Amazon Athena: Time Zone Change

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, timestamp-with-timezone, trino

I need to change a UTC timestamp to 'US/Eastern' timestamp without changing the date and time - essentially update only the timezone information and later convert that to a different timezone.

For example (what I need):

'2021-06-09 19:00:36.000000' UTC -->  '2021-06-09 19:00:36.000000' US/Eastern

Then I need to convert that to 'America/New_York'.

'2021-06-09 19:00:36.000000' US/Eastern --> '2021-06-09 16:00:36.000000' America/Los Angeles

---

When I try the query below, it's not giving me the correct results, since it is converting from UTC to America/Los Angeles. When it should be US/Eastern to America/Los Angeles.

```sql
SELECT id
, date_utc 
, CAST(date_utc AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los Angeles') AS date_la
FROM call_records
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work for Athena, as it's based on a very old version of Presto/Trino.

In recent versions of Trino ([formerly known as PrestoSQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)), you can do this:

- Cast the `timestamp with time zone` to `timestamp` to remove the timezone part.
- Then, use [`with_timezone`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?highlight=with_timezone#with_timezone) to reinterpret the resulting `timestamp` in `US/Eastern`.
- Finally, use [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#time-zone-conversion) to change the time zone of the resulting `timestamp with time zone` while preserving the instant.

Take a look at the example below:

```
trino:tiny> WITH t(ts) AS (VALUES TIMESTAMP '2021-06-09 19:00:36.000000 UTC')
         -> SELECT with_timezone(cast(ts as timestamp(6)), 'US/Eastern') AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles'
         -> FROM t;
                     _col0
------------------------------------------------
 2021-06-09 16:00:36.000000 America/Los_Angeles
(1 row)
```